# Booting from a live USB fails: cyclic rebooting

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

I faced a rather odd problem. It's a relatively new computer (built in September). Back then, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (now running 6.3.13). Windows is running in parallel, with refInd as the boot loader.

Recently, I needed to boot into a live USB and I could not anymore.

After selecting a grub entry (e.g. Try Ubuntu or Install, also in safe graphics mode) the PC just reboots in the first 10 sec. No error pops up (modified grub config to see possible critical errors).

My Ubuntu and Windows seem to boot well, although I had rarely also random reboots of Ubuntu at the startup (before login page), but I don't see something weird in the logs except of ACPI errors.

Of course, I rechecked/swapped the USB/ports sticks (could boot well on another PC), made the bootable images with different programs/verified signature, checksum.  I tried 4 different distributions: Ubuntu 22.04.03 (6.2), Ubuntu 23.10 (6.5), latest Arch (6.5.9) and Fedora 39 (6.5). Interestingly, Arch did boot well from the second time (first time it worked a bit though) and I could even make some backups, ping internet and start the installation (was curious if it will), but it rebooted while loading packages from the internet.

As I rememner, a month ago I updated BIOS and Intel ME firmware since the first installation, also set XMP profile. Of course secureboot and fastboot are deactivated. Also I tried with Compatibility support module On and Off. Play around with different bios settings (e.g. some related to the USB). "`nomodeset`", "`noacpi`"  as kernel boot parameters do not work, seems that "`acpi=off`" does, but is it really a solution? I also tried to bypass the GPU and connected the monitor directly to the motherboard -- no difference. Finally, I ran memtest for 10 hours and got an error-free 10 Passes. Do you have an idea what is going on?

Maybe an interesting point to mention. A month ago my Windows (my wife uses it for Adobe stuff), started to randomly freeze (linux worked well). I found out it was a problem with its power management scheme, I switched to high preference power profile and in BIOS: enabled ON XMP I (Ai Tweaker, Ai Overclock Tuner, XMP I), enabled Sync All Cores (Ai Tweaker, Performance Core Ratio), disabled C-States (Advanced menu, CPU configuration, CPU Power Management). Can the issues be related?

The specs:

1. MB: ASUS TUF GAMING B760M-PLUS Motherboard Socket Intel LGA 1700
2. CPU: Intel Core i5-13600K
3. RAM: Corsair VENGEANCE DDR5 RAM 64GB (2x32GB) 5600MHz CL40 Intel XMP iCUE
4. GPU: ASUS GeForce Dual RTX 3060 12GB -545 proprietary driver is installed
5. ASUS ROG Strix 850G Power Supply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed after the bios update and apparently related to the power managment of the CPU by the default settings, so it is unstable at low loads. After some trials, I could get:

`mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank: 3`

in the BIOS I changed the CPU voltage (went down, actually it was at around 1.5V), set Sync All Cores and another Load Line Calibration (from 3 to 4) and the problem is gone.